# Function not working for array

Tags: r, function, date

I wish to get a certain date format.

What I currently have is:

```
x$column <- Date ("2017-03-17", "2016-08-06".......)
```

What I am after is:

```
x$column <- char or Date ("2017-03", "2016-08",.....)
```

I wrote the below function but this doesn't work. How do i get it to correctly format the date?

```
    conv <- function(a)
    {
     mm<-strsplit(a,"-")[[1]][2]
     yyyy<-strsplit(a,"-")[[1]][3]
     com <- paste(mm,yyyy,sep="-")
     return (com)
    }
```

Comment: Just use `format(x$column, format = "%Y-%m")`

Comment: There is a yearmon class defined in the zoo package.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer and 42, thanks for your help guys, but I seek to make these functions fast. They take a lot of time. I basically want to optimize the conversion, please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
x<-as.Date("2017-03-17")
x
[1] "2017-03-17"
format(as.Date(x),"%Y-%m")
[1] "2017-03"
```

Comment: This takes a lot of time, the only motivation to write function is to minimize time. I was using that earlier. Nevertheless, appreciate your help :)